# The package "libpango" has a problem, blocking installation of other packages, how do I fix it?

Tags: package-management, configuration, dependencies

I get the following errors while trying to install any package.

> Package: libpango1.0-0 Error: libpango1.0-0:amd64 1.30.0-0ubuntu3
>   cannot be configured because libpango1.0-0
>
> Package: libgtk-3-0 Error: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>
> Package: firefox Error: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>
> Package: firefox-globalmenu Error: dependency problems - leaving
>   unconfigured
>
> Package: flashplugin-installer Error: dependency problems - leaving
>   unconfigured

I tried to configure libpango1.0-0 but i got the following error:

> libpango1.0-0:amd64 1.30.0-0ubuntu3 cannot be configured because
>   libpango1.0-0:i386 is in a different version (1.30.0-0ubuntu2)

I appreciate your assistance.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was solved with

> sudo aptitude reinstall libpango1.0-0

Actually i don't understand what it did. It removed a lot of packages then every thing was back to normal after

> sudo apt-get update

I hope this answer helps somebody else